# SQL query in where clause group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already searched on Google for this but still I can't get the correct solution for my problem.

All I want is to get the result in each field in where clause. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN 
  -- INSERT INTO tmp_sr_accountsales (REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, TransDate, SALESTYPE, STDTERMS, Amount)
  SELECT     act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount2, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount3, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount4, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount5, 
             intyear                                                     AS intyear, 
             intyear1                                                    AS intyear2, 
             intyear2                                                    AS intyear3, 
             intyear3                                                    AS intyear4, 
             intyear4                                                    AS intyear5 
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust 
  ON         ( 
                        act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE      ( 
                        act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND       ( 
                                   year(act.atdate) IN( intyear, 
                                                       intyear1, 
                                                       intyear2, 
                                                       intyear3, 
                                                       intyear4 ) ) ); 

END;
```

If you can see the code :

```
 WHERE
(
    act.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL
    AND act.CUSTOMER LIKE theCustomer
    AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType
    AND(
        YEAR(act.ATDATE) IN(
            intYear,
            intYear1,
            intYear2,
            intYear3,
            intYear4
        )
    )
);
```

That one that was inside the `IN (intYear,intYear1,intYear2,intYear3,intYear4)`
they are have different year value. and i want to get the result of each of them. Is it possible to get their result 1 by 1? Because the result of that code will just add all of the data that was selected in that query.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific functions used.)

Comment: Try to improve the code formatting. If I have to side-scroll to read, I just leave.

Comment: This isn't SQL Server. `IFNULL` function does not exist there.

Comment: How can we possibly help without sample data? It's a data related question something to do with what is **inside** intYear, intYear1, intYear2, intYear3, intYear4. Plus **IFNULL()** is a MySQL(ish) function, so please choose the correct database tag. It cannot be SQL Server which uses ISNULL() as an equivalent.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly you want to group the data by year. You can try this query.

```
   SELECT 
        act.REFERENCENO, 
        act.CUSTOMER, 
        act.ATDATE TransDate, 
        act.SALESTYPE, 
        cust.STDTERMS, 
        SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)) AS Amount, 
        YEAR(act.ATDATE) AS intYear 
    FROM 100_actual_transaction act 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (act.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
    WHERE (act.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL 
        AND act.CUSTOMER LIKE theCustomer 
        AND act.SALESTYPE LIKE theSalesType 
        AND (YEAR(act.ATDATE)IN (intYear,intYear1,intYear2,intYear3,intYear4)) );
    GROUP BY
        act.REFERENCENO, 
        act.CUSTOMER, 
        act.ATDATE TransDate, 
        act.SALESTYPE, 
        cust.STDTERMS,
        YEAR(act.ATDATE)
```

Comment: yes correct i want them as a group by year then if you can see the                  SUM(IFNULL(act.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) - IFNULL(act.DISCOUNTAMNT, 0)) AS Amount, i want to get the each amount of each year so just like this:  in intYear that equal to 2017 .. the total amount in that year is just like this 9,782,123.00 after that i also want to get the 2nd intYear1 total amount for that year just let's say intYear1 is equal to 216 so i also want to get the total amount of that year. did you get my point? please help

Comment: Do you want to sum current year with previous years? İ mean do you want cumulative total  of amount by years?

Comment: yes, i want the total amount by years. i want to get each of the total amount in each year. can you help me what query that i will use? actually if i will just query 1 of them i will get the total amount of that specific year. i tries to query them 1 by 1 so i will get each results in each year but sad to say it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using mssql?

Comment: nope.. im just using storedprocedure .. because i want to display it to the crystal report

Comment: Actually, I asked which database are you using? MySql, MsSql Oracle etc.. Because IfNull is a MySQL function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all you need to do is a set of unions?

```
  SELECT     intyear                                                    AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear

UNION ALL

  SELECT     intyear1                                                    AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear1

UNION ALL

  SELECT     intyear2                                                    AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear2

UNION ALL

  SELECT     intyear3                                                    AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear3

UNION ALL

  SELECT     intyear4                                                   AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear4

UNION ALL

  SELECT     intyear5                                                    AS Yr,
             act.referenceno, 
             act.customer, 
             act.atdate transdate, 
             act.salestype, 
             cust.stdterms, 
             Ifnull( act.totalamount, 0 )- Ifnull( act.discountamnt, 0 ) AS amount
  FROM       100 _actual_transaction act 
  INNER JOIN 000 _customer cust ON  act.customer = cust.customername ) 
  WHERE  act.referenceno IS NOT NULL 
             AND        act.customer LIKE thecustomer 
             AND        act.salestype LIKE thesalestype 
             AND        year(act.atdate) = intyear5
```

Once you have "unpivotted" the data into more rows and fewer columns, you can then use GROUP BY and SUM() over those rows to get "per year values"

Comment: thanks for your help. but it still didn't work. it only display the first query , only the first intYear query works.

Comment: it's still didn't work .. only the first query work. the others didn't work even i use union all. any suggestion?

Comment: "any suggestion"? YES! 1: **provide some sample data** 2: then, an **expected result** based on that sample. It might only be 6 or so rows of data (one per year at least), you can hide anything that is private. do not use images, use formatted text, ADD IT INTO YOUR QUESTION. No amount of words will substitute for those 2 actions

Comment: by the way "it didn't work" means absolutely nothing at this end (e.g. it could mean smoke appeared from the screen)  if "nothing appears" then that is a DATA ISSUE (which only you can solve because you got the data, not us)